# JQuery validation - how to set the title attribute to the error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

In JQuery validation the default behavior on an error is to create a label like so:

```
<label for="FirstName" generated="true" class="error">This field is required.</label>
```

Is it possible to change it so that it will output this instead (with a title attribute set to the error message)?

```
<label for="FirstName" generated="true" class="error" title="This field is required.">This field is required.</label>
```

I've tried the highlight method, but the label has not been created yet:

```
$("#form").validate({
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        var label = $("label[for=" + element.id + "]");  // but label doesn't exist yet so this doesnt work
        if (label && label.length > 0) {  // label.length is always 0
            label.attr('title', label.text());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok try this...

```
$("#form").validate({
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var label = $("label[for=" + element.id + "]");
            if (label && label.length > 0) { 
                label.attr('title', label.text());
            }
        }, 10);     
    }
});
```

basically we just delay the part where we set the title attribute for 10ms so we are sure that the label element is created first.

hope this helps

Comment: yeah but I think that's the closest we could get to success callback's counterpart...

Answer (score 0):

try this instead.

```
var validator = $('#form1').validate({
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, message) {
            var errorMessage = validator.errorMap[element.name]
            $(element).attr('title', errorMessage);
        }
    });
```

no hacks required

Answer (score 0):

I'am a bit late, but stumbled upon this question, and another solution would be to use the errorPlacement callback.

editid: also remove the generated attribute, else the message text gets refreshed after editing the field when the message is re-applied.

```
var validator = $('#form1').validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    element.attr('title', error.text());
    error.text('!');
    error.removeAttr('generated');
    error.appendTo(element.parent());
    return true;
  }
}
```